# What is the token for unsigned short in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, token

What are the token for unsigned short in objective-c?
I wanted to use this for unichar character
is it %u?

Comment: everywhere I'm looking I see `@"%hu"`, but I haven't found the definitive Apple documentation proof yet.

Comment: That information is in the Xcode Documentation, lookup "NSLog", click  the link to "NSLogv", click the link "String Format Specifiers".

Comment: token? Are you talking about format specifiers? for what formatting function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found Apple's format specifier doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)...

And it looks like you can use "`%C`" for a 16-bit Unicode character (also known as a `unichar`).

As for my earlier `@"hu"` guess, the "`h`" is a "Length modifier specifying that a following d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a short or unsigned short argument."